# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass when rendering form inside index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure why I get undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass whenever I try to call any methods on my message class.

index.html.erb messages:

```
 <div class="callout">
  <div class="messages-box">
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <% user_status = message.user_id == current_user.id ? "reciever" : "sender" %>
      <div class="<%= user_status %> callout">
        <p><%= message.body %></p>
        <p><%= message.user.email %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= simple_form_for([@conversation, @message]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id  %>
      <%= f.submit "Add Reply", class: 'button' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

message controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :setup_conversation

  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)

    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation) if @message.save
  end

  private

  def setup_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

works fine if I remove the form or If remove the @message instance variable from the index action in the corresponding controller but I need it for the form in the index view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting case because you're getting bit by ActiveRecord collection proxies.

In this line, you assign `@messages`, which is an instance of a subclass of `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, which doesn't actually have any records from the database:

```
@messages = @conversation.messages
```

What it does have, however, is a reference to the instance of `Conversation` that you've already assigned to `@conversation`.

On the next line, you create a new instance of `Message` associated with the same `@conversation`:

```
@message = @conversation.messages.new
```

You still haven't made any SQL queries at this point. Then we get into rendering, where you call `each` on `@messages`, which triggers the query:

```
@message.each do |message|
  ...
end
```

Because `CollectionProxy` is more sophisticated than a simple `AssociationRelation`, it coalesces the data from your database — saved records with a `User` association — with the new data in the collection — your non-persisted `@message`.

The result is that inside of this block, the last `message.user` is `nil`, having not been set. This doesn't explode on the previous lines because Ruby is happy to render `message.body` (which is nil) and compare `nil` with `foo@example.com`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I had a feeling it was something to do with the message instance being lumped in with the messages collection but I couldn't  figure out the why.  Your explanation explains it perfectly.  Any recommendations on how I can work around this?

Comment: @NormanChan It doesn't look like you need the new record to be built from the association, so I would switch to `@message = Message.new` without referencing the conversation. Your `create` action and your `form_for` would still use both `@conversation` and `@message`, as you have them.